# How to perform two tasks at once

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a card in image format with the front and back side, I intend to show both sides and I created a method with thread in the period of a few seconds to show each side. The problem is that it simply shows one side and I want to see both sides within a minimum of 5 seconds

```
        Thread t1 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int numberOfSeconds = 0;
            while (numberOfSeconds < 5)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);

                numberOfSeconds++;
            }

       ImgCCF.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agtmovel.Img.cartFront.png");

        });

        Thread t2 = new Thread(() =>
        {
            int numberOfSeconds = 0;
            while (numberOfSeconds < 8)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10);

                numberOfSeconds++;
            }


            ImgCCF.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agtmovel.Img.cartBack.png");

        });
        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();

        //t1.Join();
        //t2.Join();
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all avoid using directly `Thread` and use `Task` instead. They are easier to use and they better handle threads.

So you can do that like this:

```
private async Task FlipImagesAsync()
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); // I'm not entirely sure about the amount of seconds you want to wait here

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ImgCCF.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agtmovel.Img.cartFront.png");
            ImgCCF.IsVisible = true;
            ImgCCV.IsVisible = false;
        });

        await Task.Delay(8000); // I'm not entirely sure about the amount of seconds you want to wait here

        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ImgCCV.Source = ImageSource.FromResource("Agtmovel.Img.cartBack.png");
            ImgCCV.IsVisible = true;
            ImgCCF.IsVisible = false;
        });
    }
}
```

`Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` is necessary so that that change is done on the UI thread.

You can call it by using `Task.Run(this.FlipImagesAsync());`

HIH

Comment: Thanks, I wanted is that in the period that shows one side the other is hidden, so successively as if it were a non-stop loop

Comment: I have another problem with xaml one image appears underneath the other and the process and exchange does not happen. You can take a look at xaml and help fix it so both images appear in the same place only one at a time.

Comment: You don't need 2 images to accomplished this. Just delete the stack layout with the `ImgCCV` in it and use only `ImgCCF` so the effect is done changing the source of the image in a loop. If you need the 2 images for other reasons then you need to change the visibility of the 2 images accordingly in the loop so always there is just one of them visible

Comment: In this case should I make a check? if image x appears the image y should be should be off? Because what I really need is in the same layout in the center show the two images one at a time in this case. so I had put two stacklayout. Sorry for the successive questions I'm still a beginner.

Comment: There I've updated the answer just change `IsVisible` on both cards accordingly

Comment: I still have two doubts and I do not know how I can mention you to help me.

Comment: you can mention someone using at (@)